# sum numpy array at given indices

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I want to add the values of a vector:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='d')
```

to the values of another vector:

```
c = np.array([10, 10, 10], dtype='d')
```

at position given by another array (of the same size of `a`, with values `0 <= b[i] < len(c)`)

```
b = np.array([2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2], dtype='int32')
```

This is very simple to write in pseudo code:

```
for I in range(b.shape[0]):
    J = b[I]
    c[J] += a[I]
```

Something like this, but vectorized (length of `c` is some hundreds in real case).

```
c[0] += np.sum(a[b==0]) # 27 (10 + 1 + 3 + 5 + 8)
c[1] += np.sum(a[b==1]) # 25 (10 + 2 + 6 + 7)
c[2] += np.sum(a[b==2]) # 23 (10 + 0 + 4 + 9)
```

My initial guess was:

```
c[b] += a
```

but only last values of `a` are summed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to get ID based weighted summations and then add with `c`, like so -

```
np.bincount(b,a) + c
```